# Sencha Touch Ext.data.JsonP

Tags: php, extjs

My question is as follows, but first I want to say hello. :-)

I have a web application and a mobile web app. Both are running on different vhosts I created.

Now I want my mobile app to fetch informations from my web app (for example guest book entries, ...).

Therefore I did in my js-file of my mobile app:

```
    Ext.data.JsonP.request({
        url : 'http://loc.webapp/requestHandler.php',
        callbackKey : 'callback',
        params : {"name" : "peter"},
        success : function(res) {
            alert("OK");
        },
        failure : function() {
            alert("FAIL");
        }
    });
```

My php file requestHandler.php of my web app looks like this:

```
<?php
echo json_encode("Hello");
```

In firebug I can see, the request is ok (Code 200). I can see Hello, too :-).. But until the js-code runs into 
the success / failure case it takes around 30 seconds. Do I need to change settings of my apache server?

I would be very happy for an answer.

whitecloud

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your result within a function, named after your `callbackKey`, something like this:

```
echo "callback(" . json_encode("Hello") . ")";
```

Comment: Are you sure? If you look in the example app inside the sencha touch sdk package named "ajax" you will see, that a success key is defined... And my success function will be called too... But I dont know why it is called after 30 seconds...

Comment: Have you tried it?  The response should look something like `myCallbackKey({my: 'json'})`.  See the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP

Comment: Yes and it worked. But in the example app in sencha folder there is a callback method too which is executed instantly after ajax finished.. In my code it is waiting around 30 seconds.